# Swift: why MKPointAnnotation and not MKAnnotation. Errors out with "'MKAnnotation' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers"

Tags: ios, swift

In order to add an annotation to the mapview in Swift, I have this code that works eg:

let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(55.55, -77.77)

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = myLocation
annotation.title = "Some place"
map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

But my question is, map.addAnnotation expects the type 'MKAnnotation', and NOT 'MKPointAnnotation' as below.
map.addAnnotation(annotation: MKAnnotation)

and if I create an instance of MKAnnotation,i.e,
let annotation =  MKAnnotation()
I get an error "'MKAnnotation' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers" and can't set the properties like annotation.coordinate or title etc.

So why doesn't this work
let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(55.55, -77.77)

```
let annotation = MKAnnotation() //error
annotation.coordinate = myLocation //property not accessible
annotation.title = "Some place" //property not accessible
map.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

---

Comment: command clicking on the 'MKAnnotation' within Map.addAnnotation(annotation: MKAnnotation) gives useful hints of the protocol and the mandatory and optional properties that it expects

Comment: The programming guide ( Location and Maps) has  clear step-by-step instructions - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol, not a class, so you can't directly instantiate it, you can only instantiate classes which conform to it. `MKPointAnnotation` is a class and does conform to the `MKAnnotation` protocol so you can instantiate and use it directly.

Comment: Did you mean to say MKPointAnnotation in the second line of your answer where in you refer it as a class?

Comment: I think you'll just need to scan the classes in the framework you're using to get an idea

Comment: Thanks Wain ! much appreciated.